# Replacing values with names

Tags: r

I'm using the baseball data from corrgram. I only use its first 6 columns.

```
sport = baseball[ , 1:6]
```

I want to replace values with names. If the value in `Hits` column of baseball data is above its average, I want to label the value as `"above"` and if it's below its average, I want to label it as `"below"`.

I counted the average of its `Hits` column.

```
average = mean((sport)[ , "Hits"])
```

And then:

```
for (i in 1:dim(sport)[1]){
    if (sport[i, "Hits"] < average)
        sport[i, "Hits"] = ordered(sport[i, "Hits"], labels = c("below"))
    if (sport[i, "Hits"] > average)
        sport[i, "Hits"] = ordered(sport[i, "Hits"], labels = c("above"))
}
```

However, my code doesn't work and it gives 1 in all the rows of its column.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose your data looks like this:

```
sport = c(1,2,3,4,5,6)
average = mean(sport)
```

Then you may use **ifelse** approach:

```
result = ifelse(sport<average, "bellow", "above")
```

Comment: you do not need the `lappy` since `ifelse` will return a vector already

Answer (score 1):

Using `dplyr` you can do this:

```r
library(corrgram)
library(dplyr)

data("baseball")

baseball %>% 
  tibble::as_tibble() %>% # just for the nice printing
  select(1:6) %>% 
  mutate(hits_cat = if_else(Hits < mean(Hits, na.rm = TRUE), "below", "above"),
         hits_cat = ordered(hits_cat, levels = c("below", "above")))

#> # A tibble: 322 × 7
#>              Name League   Team Position Atbat  Hits hits_cat
#>            <fctr> <fctr> <fctr>   <fctr> <int> <int>    <ord>
#>  1 Andy Allanson       A    CLE       C    293    66    below
#>  2 Alan Ashby          N    HOU       C    315    81    below
#>  3 Alvin Davis         A    SEA       1B   479   130    above
#>  4 Andre Dawson        N    MON       OF   496   141    above
#>  5 A Galarraga         N    MON       1B   321    87    below
#>  6 A Griffin           A    OAK       SS   594   169    above
#>  7 Al Newman           N    MON       2B   185    37    below
#>  8 A Salazar           A    KC        SS   298    73    below
#>  9 Andres Thomas       N    ATL       SS   323    81    below
#> 10 A Thornton          A    CLE       DH   401    92    below
#> # ... with 312 more rows
```

Answer (score 0):

The `ifelse` command is a vectorized form of `if` and `else`, very handy for this sort of thing.

`ifelse(sport$Hits >= mean(sprt$Hits), "above","below")`

In terms of your code, you do not need the `ordered` call within the loops and you should make use of the else command, since if the hits is not below the average then it must be above (or equal to).

```
for (i in 1:nrow(sport)){
    if (sport[i,"Hits"] < average){
        sport[i,"Hits"] <- "below"
    } else{
        sport[i,"Hits"] <- "above"
    }
}
```